# spring boot and hibernate 5 - EntityManagerFactory session management

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, dao

I'm working on my first web app with Spring-boot and hibernate.

I've written my first DAO like this :

```
package myapplication.orderinfo;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

@Component
public class OrderInfoDaoImpl implements OrderInfoDao {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public List<OrderInfo> getOrderInfoDetails() {
        Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery criteria = builder.createQuery(OrderInfo.class);
        Root contactRoot = criteria.from(OrderInfo.class);
        criteria.select(contactRoot);
        return session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

    }

    public List<OrderInfo> getOrderInfo(String typeName) {
        Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery criteria = builder.createQuery(OrderInfo.class);
        Root contactRoot = criteria.from(OrderInfo.class);
        criteria.where(builder.equal(contactRoot.get("typeName"), typeName));
        return session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

    }
}
```

Is it correct to call the entityManagerFactory in each method like this?
I've read some articles on this, I understood that the session is closed by the tool at the end of each query, is this correct?

Everything looks fine at startup, but after a few queries in the application I've got this kind of crash :

```
Hibernate: select distinct orderinfo0_.projectLeader as col_0_0_ from t_orderInfo orderinfo0_
2018-11-12 15:12:11.746  WARN 11360 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2018-11-12 15:12:11.747 ERROR 11360 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
2018-11-12 15:12:11.752 ERROR 11360 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause

java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:669) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
```

I'm wondering if this coming from my implementation / usage of the Hibernate session.

Any help will be appreciate :o)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you don't close a session. Also, better, to properly work with transactions.

You can check this approach, if you want to work with the session and tranaxctions manually
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36278975/3405171

Probably you will need to read about Spring `@Transactional` annotation and Spring Data, if you have not done it yet.

Comment: Well I "don't want to" work with transaction manually, I found an example with implementation of DAO and used it. As suggested, I read Spring Data related articles and then I saw that people seems to prefer repository usage instead of DAO. So I switched to repo, It's look fine now. Thank you for pointing me the direction!